# Selecting text not inside an element

Tags: javascript

I have this as the HTML:

```
<div itemprop="name">
       <a title="Doe, John" href="link to his page">
           <span class="prefix"></span>
           "Doe, John"
           <span class="suffix"></span>
      </a>
   </div>
```

I want to select "Doe, John" but it's outside of any element. I've tried various permutations of var name = document.querySelector using innerHTML, text(), and nodeType, but no luck.

Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All content really should be inside of an element, and if not, it will ultimately be inside of the `body`. In your case, we know it's inside of the `a` element, so we can start there.

One way is to locate it by checking the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) for a `text node` that is the one you want.

```js
// loop through all the child nodes within the anchor
document.querySelector("a").childNodes.forEach(function(node){
  // Text nodes are nodeType: 3
  if(node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue !== ""){
    console.log(node.nodeValue.trim()); 
  }
});
```

```html
<div itemprop="name">
       <a title="Doe, John" href="link to his page">
           <span class="prefix"></span>
           "Doe, John"
           <span class="suffix"></span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Since we also know that the text you want comes after the `span` with a class of `prefix`, we can navigate there and get the [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

```js
// loop through all the child nodes within the anchor
console.log(document.querySelector("span.prefix").nextSibling.nodeValue.trim());
```

```html
<div itemprop="name">
       <a title="Doe, John" href="link to his page">
           <span class="prefix"></span>
           "Doe, John"
           <span class="suffix"></span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @user42760 You're welcome. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control of HTML then here is the way to specifically select the `Doe, John`

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.prefix').parentElement.innerText
console.log(a)
```

```html
<div itemprop="name">
   <a title="Doe, John" href="link to his page">
      <span class="prefix"></span>
      "Doe, John"
      <span class="suffix"></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there could be other text in the other elements that you want to avoid.

If so, it's quite simple. Text is held in a TextNode, which can be accessed as a sibling of other elements (among other ways). So select the `span.prefix` node and use `.nextSibling`.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("span.prefix").nextSibling.data.trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div itemprop="name">
       <a title="Doe, John" href="link to his page">
           <span class="prefix"></span>
           "Doe, John"
           <span class="suffix"></span>
      </a>
</div>
```